# Cannot use process substitution during docker build because bash goes into posix mode

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

In a Dockerfile, I want to use process substitution:

```
RUN echo <(echo '$DATA:'"$DATA")
```

But `docker build` runs every RUN command with `/bin/sh`. Apparently being run as `sh` causes bash to switch to POSIX mode, which does not allow process substitution:

> ```
> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> ```

I tried switching off POSIX mode:

```
RUN set +o posix && echo <(echo '$DATA:'"$DATA")
```

But it seems the syntax error happens even before the first command is run. Same if I replace `&&` with `;`.

Note that the command (even the one that I used as a simplified example here) contains both single and double quotes, so I can't simply prepend `bash -c`.

The used shell is actually a bash, but it is invoked as `/bin/sh` by docker:

> ```
> Step 7 : RUN ls -l /bin/sh
> ---> Running in 93a9809e12a7
> lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Dec 28 03:38 /bin/sh -> /bin/bash
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you have `bash` in your image being built, then you can change the shell invokation by using the `SHELL` command, which I described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029605/1111557).

You can use `SHELL [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]`. Consider:

```
$ docker build --no-cache - < <(echo '
> FROM fedora
> RUN cat <(echo hello world)
> ')
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM fedora
 ---> ef49352c9c21
Step 2/2 : RUN cat <(echo hello world)
 ---> Running in 573730ced3a3
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(echo hello world)'
The command '/bin/sh -c cat <(echo hello world)' returned a non-zero code: 1
$ docker build --no-cache - < <(echo '
> FROM fedora
> SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
> RUN cat <(echo hello world)
> ')
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM fedora
 ---> ef49352c9c21
Step 2/3 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
 ---> Running in e78260e6de42
Removing intermediate container e78260e6de42
 ---> ff6ec782a9f6
Step 3/3 : RUN cat <(echo hello world)
 ---> Running in afbb42bba5b4
hello world
Removing intermediate container afbb42bba5b4
 ---> 25f756dcff9b
Successfully built 25f756dcff9b
```

Comment: looks like StackOverflow's syntax highlighting broke on this. I'm not sure if or how I could fix that lol

Comment: Easiest fix is to just turn it off; see edit doing so. :) --- btw, if you really want to use the older four-space-indent syntax, `<!-- language: none -->` prior to an indented block will do the same.

Comment: Heh I just used "older four space indent syntax" because that's what I knew StackOverflow used. Is there another better syntax now?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `sh` is not `bash`, you can't use process substitution in `shell` mode directly; you need to spawn a `bash` session (non-login, non-interactive here):

```
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo <(echo '$DATA:'\"$DATA\")" ]
```

Here i have used the `json` (aka `exec`) form to make sure the quotes are easily managed, here you just need to escape quotes around `$DATA`: `\"$DATA\"` -- to prevent `json` interpretation beforehand.

---

If your `sh` is in fact `bash`, this should do:

```
RUN "echo <(echo '$DATA:'"$DATA")"
```

Also this just outputs the file descriptor, i am not rally sure about your plan.

Comment: It is in fact bash, it's just not called as such. I made that clear in an edit.

Comment: That second RUN command gives me `container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"echo <(echo '$DATA:'\\\"$DATA\\\")\": executable file not found in $PATH"`. Outputting the file descriptor is just to show that it works.

Comment: @AndreKR Ooops, my bad. Check now.

Comment: That gives: `/bin/sh: echo <(echo ':'): command not found` Otherwise it is virtually identical to my non-working example.